# Irregular behaviour when mixing \pagestyle and \newpage and \marginenote

Tags: pdftex, fancyhdr, marginnote, subfiles

This might be a newbie question, but I have been struggling for hours to find out what is going on and still it does not make any sense.

I managed to create a MWE, but when I gradually transfer to the actual case everything falls apart.

I am using a relative complicated Latex in multiple files. Please consider the following master:

http://pastebin.com/CCXJJzpR

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt,british]{report}

%DEBUG variable will be used to provide extra information as a margin note!
\newif\ifDEBUG 
\DEBUGtrue

\author{MEEE }
%\title{Minimal PhD}
\title{\ifDEBUG\marginnote{DE-BUG mode!!!!}[1cm]\fi Big title}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}


\usepackage{subfiles} %for multiple files
%\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}

\usepackage{syntonly}
%\syntaxonly %when commented out, it DOES produce pdf file.


\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,epstopdf} %for colour in images, for images, for auto-conversion
\usepackage{ifpdf}


\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[UKenglish, british]{babel}
\usepackage{hyphenat} %to hypen words in the text, use \hyp{} instead of direct -
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{nomencl}
% the following is useful when we have the old nomencl.sty package
\providecommand{\printnomenclature}{\printglossary}
\providecommand{\makenomenclature}{\makeglossary}
\makenomenclature

\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfauthor={meee}, pdftitle={ pdffffftitle },  pdftex,  bookmarks=true, bookmarksnumbered=true, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1, breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 1}, colorlinks=true, backref=page]{hyperref}

\newif\ifpdf
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
    \pdffalse
\else
    \pdfoutput=1
    \pdftrue
\fi

\ifpdf
  % put here packages only for the PDF:
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps}   
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{.eps}{pdf}{.pdf}{`epstopdf #1} %\includegraphics[width=7in]{result_1} %without extension
  \hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}
\else
% put here packages only for the DVI:
    \hypersetup{linkscolors=black}
\fi

\makeatletter

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\greektext}{%
      \fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont\def\encodingdefault{LGR}}
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\textgreek}[1]{\leavevmode{\greektext #1}}
    \DeclareFontEncoding{LGR}{}{}
    \DeclareTextSymbol{\~}{LGR}{126}
    %% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
    \providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
    \newcommand{\lyxaddress}[1]{
    \par {\raggedright #1
    \vspace{1.4em}
    \noindent\par}
    }

    \@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
    \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
    \usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother





%headers

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{headings}

%\pagestyle{myheadings} % use page headers
% puts headers on both pages alternating even and odd numbers.  \markboth{even-text}{odd-text}
%\markboth{Modular Examples for LaTeX, August 2008, Assad Ebrahim}{(Odd Numbered Pages), (Additional Text), (Final Text)}

%
%\makeatletter
%\def~\ref{\clearpage%
%\if@twoside
%\ifodd\c@page\else
%\vspace*{\fill}
%\hfill
%\begin{center}
%This page intentionally left blank.
%\end{center}
%\vspace{\fill}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%\newpage
%\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi
%\fi
%\fi
%}
%\makeatother


%second version of intentially empty page
\newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
    \vspace*{\fill}%
    %\centering 
    \textit{This page is intentionally left blank for formatting purposes.}%
    \vspace{\fill}%
}

\makeatletter%
    \renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{
        \clearpage
        \if@twoside
            \ifodd
                \c@page
            \else
                \blankpage
            %   \thispagestyle{empty}
                \newpage
                \if@twocolumn
                    \hbox{}
                    \newpage
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
        \pagestyle{headings}
    }
\makeatother



\newcommand*\NewPage{%
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage%
}


\newcommand*\myblankpage{
    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \textit{This page is intentionally left blank for formatting purposes.}%
    \null
    \pagebreak

}

%\newcommand*\NewPage{\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}

\begin{document}


\maketitle





\myblankpage





\begin{center}
Dissertation (Full Time PhD)\\
\vspace{4cm}

\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
{\LARGE{}Meeeeee}\vspace{4cm}

\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
Supervised by
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
Somebody
\bigskip{}

\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
Date of initial registration: past
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
Date of Review Meeting: \textbf{now}
\par\end{center}


\lyxaddress{\begin{center}
Venue: \textbf{10:00am in space} 
\par\end{center}}

\newpage{}


Month... 2014

\newpage{}




\begin{flushright}
2014
\par\end{flushright}

\newpage{}




\subsection*{Declaration}

This dissertation is the result of my own work and othe stuff
\vspace{2cm}







\newpage{}


\section*{Acknowledgements}

The research has been carried out somewhere

\newpage{}

\subfile{abstract}

\newpage{}

\tableofcontents{}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\newpage{}

\settowidth{\nomlabelwidth}{EUROCONTROL}
\printnomenclature{}

\newpage{}





\subfile{phd_1_problem_description}

\subfile{phd_2_literature_review}

\subfile{phd_3_technical_report}

\subfile{phd_4_methodology_families}

\subfile{phd_5_applications}

\subfile{phd_6_conclusions}


\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\subfile{appendix_1}
\subfile{appendix_2}

\newpage{}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

and just the abstract:

http://pastebin.com/X0fxdQRH

```
    \documentclass[phd_dissertation_master2.tex]{subfiles} 



    \begin{document}

    \begin{abstract}




    \ifDEBUG
        \marginnote{Problem Description}[0cm]
    \fi

    any random text any random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textvvvvvvvv


    \ifDEBUG
        \marginnote{How to address the problem}[0cm]
    \fi

    random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textany random textvvvvvvvv






    \end{abstract}

    \end{document}
```

Everything compiles fine on pdflatex, but the final output is not quite right. More precisely, the margin notes intersect with the main text body when I include the command \newline. I accidentally found this out by trial and error from the MWE. If I do not use it, then everything is fine. If it is included, then the aforementioned error appears. All I was trying to do is to create a command that will leave a message on the even pages (the standard message 'this page was left intentionally blank').

[image]

I am satisfied with the rest of the document, I only needed to include that minor behaviour. Unfortunately, it has a massive effect and destroys my structure.

I believe that the problem comes from the mix of packages:

fancyhdr
marginnote
subfiles

but from their description there wasn't any known bad behaviour.

any suggestions?

I was trying to print any boxes around each element of the text, but I couldn't find that, either.

After following Jared's advice, the print layouts are:

[image]

[image]

They seem perfectly fine to me.

UPDATE: The code below is more minimal and still reproduces the bad behaviour. As is it delivers overalaped output. If you comment out the \newpage and comment in the \cleardoublepage, it seems to work fine.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{report}

    \newif\ifDEBUG 
    \DEBUGtrue
    %\DEBUGfalse

    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{marginnote}

    \usepackage{layout} 

    \usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

    \usepackage{subfiles} 

    \usepackage[UKenglish]{babel} 

    \newcommand*{\blankpage}{%
        \vspace*{\fill}%     
        \textit{This page is intentionally left blank more complicated}%
        \vspace{\fill}%
    }

    \makeatletter
        \renewcommand*{\cleardoublepage}{
            \clearpage
            \if@twoside
                \ifodd
                    \c@page
                \else
                    \blankpage
                    \thispagestyle{empty}
                    \newpage
                    \if@twocolumn
                        \hbox{}
                        \clearpage
                    \fi
                \fi
            \fi
            \pagestyle{headings}
        }
    \makeatother



    \begin{document} 
    \layout 
    \cleardoublepage


    \ifDEBUG
        \marginnote{BEFORE Abstract first marginnote for demonstration}[0cm]
    \fi


    some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some
     random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random

    \newpage

    %\cleardoublepage

    \begin{abstract}

    \ifDEBUG
        \marginnote{in Abstract first marginnote for demonstration}[0cm]
    \fi

    some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some
     random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random

    \end{abstract}

    \cleardoublepage

    Start main text

    \ifDEBUG
        \marginnote{first marginnote in MAIN for demonstration}[0cm]
    \fi

    some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some
     random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random


    \ifDEBUG
        \marginnote{second marginnote in MAIN for demonstration}[0cm]
    \fi

    some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some
     random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random

    \cleardoublepage

    \ifDEBUG
        \marginnote{third marginnote in MAIN for demonstration}[0cm]
    \fi

    some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some
     random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random text some random

    \end{document}
```

Any comment/advice is more than welcome.
Many thanks in advance,
C.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx, please don't link to external sites (unless you are offering to preserve those forever it makes a mess of the archives) try to make a self contained example and add it inline to your question using the `{}` button to mark up a code section

Comment: use package layout and command \layout just after \begin{document} that will print the specific sizes of parmar (margin notes) and text width, and a diagram of how these spaces distribute in the document's page. If they print printed overlapped then use command \setlenght for one (par mar or text width) in order to prevent the overlap, as example margin notes width + text width must not be greater than actual page width

Comment: Any further opinions?